# Delete multiple row with ids without foreach and postman test

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a little problem. But I dont know why it doesnt work. And I dont know how to post all ids by postman.

I am using unit of work with generic repository. I want to send int[] ids to my controller. I dont want to send entity. I searched a lot it today. And I changed my code. But what is problem now?

This is my repostiroy:

```
  public async Task DeleteRangeAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet.Where(predicate);
            await Task.Run(() => { _dbSet.RemoveRange(query.AsNoTracking()); });
        }
```

This is my KulturManager:

```
 public async Task<IResult> HardDeleteRangeAsync(int[] ids)
        {
            await UnitOfWork.Kulturs.DeleteRangeAsync(c => ids.Contains(c.Id));
            await UnitOfWork.SaveAsync();
            return new Result(ResultStatus.Success, Messages.Info("Kultur", "HardDelete"));
        }
```

And this is my KulturController:

```
   [HttpDelete("{ids}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> HardDeleteRangeAsync(int[] ids)
        {
            var result = await _kulturManager.HardDeleteRangeAsync(ids);
            return Ok(result.Message);
        }
```

Thank you for help

Comment: `localhost:5283/api/kultur this is my route. I want to send int[] ids. For example ids = [7,8]`So you want to  send ids with the url,like `localhost:5283/api/kultur?ids[0]=7&&ids[1]=8`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't fetch all the entities you want to delete.  Instead create stub entities for RemoveRange.  If you don't have a common base class, this requires reflection, but with a common entity base class you can do it like this:

```
public void DeleteRange<T>(int[] ids) where T: BaseEntity, new()
{
    _dbSet.RemoveRange(ids.Select(i => new T() { Id = i }).ToList());
}
```

or if the method is in a generic class, the method would look like

```
public void DeleteRange(int[] ids) 
{
    _dbSet.RemoveRange(ids.Select(i => new T() { Id = i }).ToList());
}
```

And there's no reason to mark this as Async now since it doesn't do any database access.

Comment: Hello, thx for help. I changed my codes. İf ı send a id it works. But how can i send 2 or more ids at same time? I couldnt find any guide for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "send 2 or more ids at same time"?

Comment: http://localhost:5283/api/kultur/ this is my route. I want to send int[] ids. For example ids = [7,8]

Comment: Does your service have a OpenAPI/Swagger page?  It will show you.

Comment: No it is postman.

Comment: That's a different question, but read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-6.0